# 'with' tag problems in django

Tags: django, templates, tags

I have a model "Invoice" with a method

```
def item_objects(self):
    return self.invoiceitem_set.filter(kind='item')
```

I then have a template with that model in its context "invoice"

in that template I use a with tag to try and cache that item_objects

```
{% with item_object=invoice.item_objects%}
    {{item_object}}
    {{item_object}}
{% endwith %}
```

Regardless I still hit the database for each time I call {{item_object}}

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your simplified code is likely hiding the problem, as the behavior you describe should not be happening. The entire purpose of the `with` template tag is to cache the results of an expensive method for use later.

However, your method, `item_objects`, returns a `QuerySet`, and when you assign it to `item_object`, it is still a `QuerySet`. `QuerySet`s are lazy-loaded, so up to this point, no database hits have been made. As a result, depending on what you actually *do* with `item_object`, you can negatively impact the query performance.

For example, the following will result in two queries to the DB, even though you're dealing with a cached `QuerySet`:

```
{{ item_object.count }}
{{ item_object|first }}
```

You need to be careful with what operations you perform on querysets and in which order. For example, if you know that you are going to loop through the queryset at some point, but you need a count first, it's actually more efficient to use `{{ item_object|length }}` instead of `{{ item_object.count }}`

Comment: using the debug tool I see that for each {{item_object}} I hit the db. I'm not looking at count or anything else just strait up.  {{item_object}}

here is the template http://pastebin.com/PJQFYYE6

Comment: Referencing the queryset itself calls `__repr__` on it. Django likely forces a new query each time since the representation is dependent on the real-time results. However, this is not something you would ever actually do in your template on purpose (i.e. you're going to loop through the queryset or perform some sort of other operation on it like a count). If you actually do something real-world, you shouldn't see multiple hits to the DB anymore.

Comment: Chris is right. I recommend looking at James Bennett's recent [Django In Depth](http://pyvideo.org/video/610/django-in-depth) session at Pycon in which he explains what triggers the evaluation of a QuerySet. Plus: changing `invoice.item_objects` to `ìnvoice.item_objects.all` would evaluate the queryset only once.